# Is it better to use arrays instead of parameter lists when designing an api for an MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, api, kohana

When writing a CRUD MVC application, would you suggest using arrays instead of long (even short) parameter lists when writing an api for your business layer (model)?

For instance, which would you suggest:

**1**

```
// Posts::getPosts(20, 0, $category, 'date_added');
static function getPosts($limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, Model_Category $category = NULL, $sort_by = NULL);
```

**2**

```
// Posts::getPosts(array('limit' => 20, 'offset' => 0, 'category' => $category, 'sort_by' => 'date_added'));
static function getPosts(array $options = NULL);`
```

1 seems a lot cleaner and less prone to bugs, but 2 seems WAY more flexible (can easily add/switch parameters without changing the api). Just looking for reasons to go either way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go with this rule of thumb:

If

- there are more than 5 arguments
- there is no logical order of the arguments
- there is not a clear logical dependency between arguments
  and/or
- most of the arguments are optional

Then it is *probably* a good idea to use an array to simulate keyword arguments. Otherwise, just go with standard arguments.

Also, consider using a [parameter object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) to do complicated method calls.

**EDIT:** What would I do with this?

```
public static function search(
  $keywords,
  $limit = NULL,
  $offset = NULL,
  Model_Post_Type $type = NULL,
  Model_Category $category = NULL
)
```

Well, with a parameter array (also known as keyword arguments in languages that support them, like Python), my personal preference would be to do this:

```
public static function search($keywords, $options = array()) {
  $default_options = array(
    'limit' => NULL,
    'offset' => NULL,
    'post_type' =>  NULL,
    'category' => NULL
  );
  extract(array_merge($default_options,$options));
  // search logic, using $keywords, $limit, $offset, $post_type, $category
}
```

This gives you a few benefits:

- Anything in `$options` is completely optional. Any required arguments should be arguments.
- Gives you complete control over the defaults of those options, even allowing for complicated expressions in the array initializer.
- Allows you to add new (optional) search options later on, while remaining backwards-compatible with existing code.
- `extract()` makes key-value pairs into variable-value pairs, so the rest of the method is completely oblivious to the fact you're using a parameter array and not normal arguments.

Comment: `public static function search($keywords, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, Model_Post_Type $type = NULL, Model_Category $category = NULL)`

Comment: Keep in mind, there may be additional params in the future, to sort the results, etc.

Answer (score 4):

With just an array, the guy who will try to call your method doesn't know which parameter(s) it expects.

And his IDE will not be able to help either...

=> He'll have to go read the documentation -- which takes time.

On the other hand, with the first solution, just looking at the declaration of the method *(and my IDE does display that when I type the name of the method)*, I know what parameters it expects.

I agree that your second solution *(array of named parameters)* is way more flexible.

But, especially when there are only a few parameters, I tend to prefer the first one -- just for the reason I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

That probably depends on what you need.  Do the parameters you use have a logical order?  Is one inapplicable without another?  It's not really a one-or-the-other-for-everything.

Because of the nature of this case, separate arguments are probably the best route.  One thing I would suggest however is that it provide more useful defaults.